# Why is scope outside of while not re-executed in a generator function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My code works well, but I still have some questions. Why `a` and `b` declarations are not re-executed? Is only the context of `while (true)` scope kept? Why?

```
function* fibonacciGen() {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 1;

    while (true) {
        sum = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = sum;
        yield sum;
    }
}

const fibonacci = fibonacciGen();

console.log(fibonacci.next().value) // -> 2
console.log(fibonacci.next().value) // -> 3
console.log(fibonacci.next().value) // -> 5
console.log(fibonacci.next().value) // -> 8
console.log(fibonacci.next().value) // -> 13
console.log(fibonacci.next().value) // -> 21
```

Comment: The function's execution *suspends* and *resumes*. There is no restarting from the top.

Comment: What @trincot said. If it *did* restart from the top, then it can never ever end. Consider `function* foo() { yield 1; yield 2; }` which, if there was constant re-execution, would do what `function* foo() { while(true) { yield 1; } }` does right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a generator function (`fibonacciGen()` here), the body of the function executes until it encounters a yield. So the `let a` and `let b` lines run when the generator is first called. At the `yield`, the function stops executing - but it's not like a `return`, because it'll continue when `.next` is called on the iterator. Calling `.next` tells a generator function to start executing again from the `yield` it last stopped at, and to continue until another `yield` is encountered.

Each time `.next()` is called, the resumed generator will finish the iteration of the `while` loop, then continue with the next iteration of the loop, running

```
sum = a + b;
a = b;
b = sum;
```

again - but not running the entire `fibonacciGen` generator function again.